# how to take array values as key value pair in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, multidimensional-array, webapi

I'm new to api. I have two arrays let it be A and B, both A and B contains json response,

Array A has the following data.

```
{
    "servers": [
        {
            
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": ,
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": ",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ],           
                      "rel": "bookmark"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "OS-EXte": "active",
            "OS-TR:instance_name": "instance-000",
            "OS-SRV-Uched_at": "20200",
            "flavor": {
                "id": "fe183ca7-610f-4db4-934",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": 
                        "rel": "bookmark"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

and so on and array B has

```
{
    "flavors": [
        {
            "name": "ti",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
         
            ],
            "ram": 8192,
            "OS-FLV-DISABLEse,
      
        },
        {
```

I need to take all the flavor id from array A which is matching in array B.

Comment: If you could show  the expected  output? getting confused with adding sum to third Array

Comment: @AjeetEppakayala need to take all the flavrs from array B which are matching in array A. i first need how to do that. then i will give the next one

Comment: On Stackoverflow you are supposed to describe your problems clear and at once.
If you can do further part once this is sorted?

Comment: @AjeetEppakayala is there a way to access flavors from my Array A above?

Comment: sure, there is.

Comment: You can remove adding part from question if that's not your concern.

Comment: @AjeetEppakayala  I have updated the question . now please help me with it

Comment: I can't  attempt until you provide expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let servers = [{
  flavor: {
    id: "1",
    links: [{
      rel: "bookmark"
    }]
  }
}, {
  flavor: {
    id: "2",
    links: [{
      rel: "any"
    }]
  }
}]

let flavors = [{
  name: "ti",
  ram: 8192,
  id: "1"
}, {
  name: "ti",
  ram: 8192,
  id: "2"
}, {
  name: "ti",
  ram: 8192,
  id: "3"
}]

let serverFlavors = servers.map(s => s.flavor.id)
let newArray = flavors.filter(f => serverFlavors.includes(f.id))
console.log(newArray)
```

If your data is json, you can [parse the json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and then do the above.

parse JSON like

```
JSON.parse(<strigifiedJSON>)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can first map all the flavor Id from Array `A` to the new Array.
And then filer Array `B` from mapped `Flavor` Array .

Assuming Servers is Array A -

```
let serverFlavor = servers.map(row => { row.flavor.id});


let filteredRam = flavors.filter(row => serverFlavor.find((a) => a == row.id));
```

Then you can use reduce function on `filteredRam` Array .